# R Shiny rCharts https server failing to load fonts.googleapis.com

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, google-apis-explorer

I got a shiny https server running, and I tried to use rCharts to plot a dTable so that I could do multi-column sort from dataTables (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956772/719016).

What I could deduct from the Console output and this explanation (http://yoast.com/wordpress-ssl-setup/) is that this rCharts table is trying to load fonts from fonts.googleapis.com via the templates/default.html in shiny:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://my.server.com/shiny/shiny_dev/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Any ideas how to fix this without admin access to the shiny server?

Can I override the fonts that are attempted to be loaded in my `server.R` or `ui.R` code?

Comment: The latest version of Shiny supports DataTables natively. I believe that would be the easiest way to solve your issue. When I next work on `dTable`, I will investigate how to fix this issue from the rCharts end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try manually loading font over https, which Google Fonts also supports.

```
 ui = bootstrapPage(
    tags$link(
      rel = "stylesheet", 
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro"
    ),
    tags$style("h1{font-family: 'Source Code Pro'}"),
    tags$h1("Test Font"),
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    plotOutput('plot')
  )
```